# Pandas df long to wide and pivot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df like such:

[image]

Here is the input data:

```
[{'Region/Province': 'PHILIPPINES', 'Commodity': 'Atis [Sugarapple]', '2018 January': '..', '2018 February': '..'}, {'Region/Province': 'PHILIPPINES', 'Commodity': 'Avocado', '2018 January': '..', '2018 February': '..'}, {'Region/Province': 'PHILIPPINES', 'Commodity': 'Banana Bungulan, green', '2018 January': '12.57', '2018 February': '12.48'}, {'Region/Province': 'PHILIPPINES', 'Commodity': 'Banana Cavendish', '2018 January': '9.96', '2018 February': '8.8'}]
```

Where the columns after `commodity` are like this: 2018 January, 2018 February.. 2018 Annual all the way up to 2021.

But I need it like this:

[image]

Where there are repeated `Commodity` names, but split by year/month with the `Amount` being it's own column. I've tried `pd.wide_to_long()` and it's close to what I need, but the years become their own columns.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put sample input in text form (so we can copy-paste it)?

Comment: You want to `melt` this dataframe. `df.melt(['Region/Preovince', 'Commodity'])`

Comment: @AndrejKesely I added the input sample

Comment: @JoshPickel @ScottBoston answer is already ok, just split the `variable` column to `Month` and `Year` afterwards.

Comment: @AndrejKesely, I feel dense, but how would I do that?

Comment: Split if required with `df[['Year','Month']] = df.variable.str.split(" ",expand=True,)`

Answer (score 5):

Try [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

```
stacked = (
    df.set_index(['Region/Province', 'Commodity'])
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='Amount')
)
stacked[['Year', 'Month']] = stacked['level_2'].str.split(expand=True)
stacked = stacked.drop('level_2', axis=1)
```

`stacked`:

```
  Region/Province               Commodity Amount  Year     Month
0     PHILIPPINES       Atis [Sugarapple]     ..  2018   January
1     PHILIPPINES       Atis [Sugarapple]     ..  2018  February
2     PHILIPPINES                 Avocado     ..  2018   January
3     PHILIPPINES                 Avocado     ..  2018  February
4     PHILIPPINES  Banana Bungulan, green  12.57  2018   January
5     PHILIPPINES  Banana Bungulan, green  12.48  2018  February
6     PHILIPPINES        Banana Cavendish   9.96  2018   January
7     PHILIPPINES        Banana Cavendish    8.8  2018  February
```

---

or [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

```
melt = df.melt(['Region/Province', 'Commodity'], value_name='Amount')
melt[['Year', 'Month']] = melt['variable'].str.split(expand=True)
melt = melt.drop('variable', axis=1)
```

`melt`:

```
  Region/Province               Commodity Amount  Year     Month
0     PHILIPPINES       Atis [Sugarapple]     ..  2018   January
1     PHILIPPINES                 Avocado     ..  2018   January
2     PHILIPPINES  Banana Bungulan, green  12.57  2018   January
3     PHILIPPINES        Banana Cavendish   9.96  2018   January
4     PHILIPPINES       Atis [Sugarapple]     ..  2018  February
5     PHILIPPINES                 Avocado     ..  2018  February
6     PHILIPPINES  Banana Bungulan, green  12.48  2018  February
7     PHILIPPINES        Banana Cavendish    8.8  2018  February
```